# how to make two calls parallel?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in my code, i need to call two services. they are independent

```
client1.call(service1);
client2.call(service2);
do something after both of them get responses
```

with the above pseudo code, it seems that the two calls are executed sequentially, i.e., client2 will not execute until client1 gives a response. since the two services are provided by two nodes, i hope that there is a kind of non-blocking mode. i.e., after client1 calls the service, it goes directly to the next line to let client2 call service2. how can i fulfill this?

thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47049/how-to-make-two-calls-parallel?/) by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 741 on 2012-10-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2012-10-29**:
I don't know if there is any *non-blocking* service call in ROS, but in case there is not... how about launching the service calls in separate threads?

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-10-29**:
thanks man. multi-threads makes me headache :-(  maybe i could give openmp a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS does not have a non blocking mode for services and it should not need one. The reason is that services should never be used for long running processes. In such cases actions are much better. See [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/11834/when-should-i-use-topics-vs-services-vs-actionlib-actions-vs-dynamic_reconfigure/) for a discussion.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-10-29**:
thanks. but the link you gave just links to this page. could you check the link again?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-29**:
Updated. Sorry. Seems like it was a bug in the answers site.

**Comment by [machinekoder](https://answers.ros.org/users/33820/machinekoder/) on 2019-10-03**:
And what if you are not in control of the implementation, let's say a robot where only service calls are available?